# Using puppeteer to scrape Squarespace analytics

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am new to Puppeteer.  I am trying to scrape the analytics page on my Squarespace site so that I can see how people are using my site.

As a first test, I am merely trying to take a screenshot of the desired page.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const CREDS = require('./creds');


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true})

  await page.goto('https://www.squarespace.com/login');

  const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '<input class="username Input-hxTtdt ipapEE" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off">';
  const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '<input class="password Input-hxTtdt ipapEE" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">';
  const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '<button class="Button-kDSBcD fATVqu" data-test="login-button"><span>Log In</span></button>';

  await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);

  await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

  await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);

  await page.waitForNavigation();

  await page.goto('https://triangle-oarfish-hk21.squarespace.com/config/analytics#activity-log');

  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: page is not defined
    at /Users/reallymemorable/Documents/scripts.scrapers/squarespace.ip.scraper/squarespace.js:8:3
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
(node:16200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16200) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really basic here about how to define a page, but it's late and I'm a bit lost.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You forgot to create the page object `const page = await browser.newPage();`
- selectors in `page.click` are in wrong shape. Use it like this `const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '.username.Input-hxTtdt.ipapEE';`
- Clicking button and waiting for navigation [should be wrapped in `Promise.all`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.9.0&show=api-pageclickselector-options)

Here is corrected your example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const CREDS = require('./creds');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.squarespace.com/login');

  const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '.username.Input-hxTtdt.ipapEE';
  const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '.password.Input-hxTtdt.ipapEE';
  const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '.Button-kDSBcD.fATVqu';

  await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);

  await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR),
  ]);

  await page.goto('https://triangle-oarfish-hk21.squarespace.com/config/analytics#activity-log');

  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I added that, but now I get this: `(node:17703) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.`

Comment: @reallymemorable I've spotted additional 2 new errors in your example.

Comment: Thanks for that.  How would I start to think about reading text from that page?  (I made the script take a screenshot just to see if I could get there.)